# How to write an XML parser using only standard libraries?

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing

I'm working on my program where I would import an XML file and scan for parser state (also Element, line number, content).

Right now, I have all the elements and line numbers stored in `vector`s of `string` and `integer`.

My question is, how can I scan for an attribute which at the end I would be able to indicate the root, children, and direct children? I have tried using `<map>` but still no clue.

Here are some examples:

[image]

Output will be

[image]

It would be easy if I used additional libraries but I would like to use the standard C/C++ library only.

Comment: Don't. Use a library. XML-parsing is hard and you will get it wrong the first 1000 attempts. If you just want to learn - it's a different story though

Comment: please don't use screenshots of text -- just copy and paste the text and use the "source code" formatting that you get when selecting the text and clicking on the `{}` button.

Answer (score 7):

If you want an XML parser, use an XML parser. Simple as that. If you don't want to use an existing one, but only use the tools that C++ gives you, you'd write your own XML parser. Doing that would be insane.

And if people tell you to e.g. use regular expressions on XML: XML is not a regular language, and you'll need a lexer that understands XML, which is an XML parser. To see what happens when you try to RegEx-analyze things like HTML, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Thank you, I'll see what I can do

Comment: @user5455138: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped you.  Thanks.